# Casting integer arrays in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust, casting, type-safety

I have an array of `u8`s which I want to turn into a (proportionally smaller) array of `u32`s without allocating any additional memory: this seems as though it should be easy (and safe), but I can't find a way to do it safely (I think I could do this using `transmute`, but apparently that uses memcpy under the hood and I don't want that).

In case this is an XY problem, what I'm really trying to do here is to read from a character device file and interpret the raw data I get back. I'm doing this as follows:

```
let mut device_file = File::open(device_path)?;
device_file.seek(SeekFrom::Start(0x3200))?;

let mut buf = [0; 0x28 * 4];
let n = device_file.read(&mut buf[..])?;
```

I then want to read this data on a word (32 bit) level. I could access four byte slices and turn them into a `u32`, but I would rather be able to reinterpret the array as an array of `u32`s of length `0x28`.

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in Rust? I'm new to the language and this is something that would be trivial in C, but perhaps there's a better way of thinking about the problem in Rust?

I appreciate that there are endianness issues at play here, but in the case that the endianness conversion I want matches the target architecture, this should be a no-op.

Comment: You say the endianness doesn't matter, but rust doesn't care. The safety model assumes you don't know the endianness, as there is no way to state in the language a specific endianness is required.

Comment: The rust way would to use an iterator or some other form of adaptor that handles the conversion on read. Is there a reason you need an array specifically?

Comment: @user1937198 `from_be_bytes` and `from_le_bytes` exist, so it seems there is some way of specifying endinaness for a conversion like this? I don't really see how this is unsafe? In the case the the endinaness matches, it's just a `reinterpret_cast` (i.e. no-op) in C, in the case that there's a mismatch, then some work is required to reorder the bytes. This should be entirely resolvable at compile time.

Comment: @user1937198
> Is there a reason you need an array specifically?

I want random access into the data and quite a bit of it can be discarded.

Comment: They don't specify the edianness of the program, they specify the endianess of the target data and give you something of unknown endianness.

Comment: If all you want is random acess, then an adaptor that implements  `Deref<Target = [i32]>` would do that.

Comment: @user1937198 yes, but this is the behavior that I want. In this particular case I want a little-endian conversion of the data and I'm running on little-endian targets so this shouldn't require any overhead.

Comment: @user1937198 >  Deref<Target = [i32]>

I'll have a look into that, thanks. It just seems slightly strange to me that this isn't something already in stdlib?

Comment: Rust has a pretty minimal stdlib. Stuff needs to have a clear concrete use case to go in.

Comment: https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-v2-safe-transmute/11431 discusses this kind of problem and suggests the [safe-transmute](https://crates.io/crates/safe-transmute) crate